# Can't get parameters via POST request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception

Want to scale a module of uploading files on server. The skeleton of the project got [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/07/ile-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp-java-web-tutorial-example.html#ixzz30Z8cINtW). Besides of pictures want to create thumbnails of them. The size of thumbnail is selected on the jsp page and sent to servlet. The problem is that I can't get that parameters via `request.getParameter("name")`. Point me please, where I am fool.

**JSP** (I think that will be enough)

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple id="file" onchange="check('file')"/><br>
    <div id="set_thumbnail" style="display: none;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" onclick="setVisible('thumbnail','sizeThumbnailInput')"/>
        <label>Create thumbnail</label>
    </div>
    <select id="sizeThumbnailInput" name="sizeThumbnail" style="display: none">
        <option value="0">SMALL(max 100x100px)</option>
        <option value="1">MEDIUM(max 250x250px)</option>
        <option value="2">BIG(max 620x620px)</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

**Servlet**

```
public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "g:\\point";
private boolean thumbnail;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path1 = "";
    String path2= "";
    String path = "";
    if (request.getParameter("thumbnail")!= null & request.getParameter("thumbnail").equals("on")){
        thumbnail = true;
    }
    //process only if its multipart content
    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                    new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                System.out.println(item.getFieldName());
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    if (item.getName().length() < 3 || item.getSize() < 3){
                        request.setAttribute("message", "File is wrong or not assigned.");
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
                        return;
                    }
                    path1 = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name;
                    item.write( new File(path1));
                    if (thumbnail){
                        path2 = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + "thumbnail_" + item.getName();
                        ResizePicture resPicture = new ResizePicture(path1, path2, ResizePicture.PictureTemplate.SMALL_IMAGE);
                        resPicture.resize();
                    }
                    path = path1 + "\n" + path2;
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully\n" + path);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        request.setAttribute("message",
                "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown on

```
if (request.getParameter("thumbnail")!= null & request.getParameter("thumbnail").equals("on")){
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do `condition1 & condition2`, always two conditions are evaluated (so in your example the param "thumbnail" can be `null`). You have to use `condition1 && condition2` since by this way `condition2` will only be evaluated if `condition1` is `true`

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, I know that. In debugger I see request.getParameter("thumbnail") as null anyhow.
I need to set thumbnail "true" only if I got "on" from jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for NPE is already mentioned in above answer that you are using `&`, Hence both conditions will be evaluated. Replacing it with `&&` will solve the issue.

You can also use an alternative, to avoid NPE and `!= null` check,

```
if ( "on".equals(request.getParameter("thumbnail")) ) {
    // Do the rest.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. NPE doesn't appear more. But never the less I get null from request.getParameter("thumbnail").

Comment: For that you can refer this question : [checking which check boxes are selected using JAVA ( a jsp)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15775412/1686291)

Comment: `boolean myCheckBox = request.getParameter( "id_of_checkbox" ) != null;` - helpful, I didn't know that.
huh, but now it returns `false` either I checked the field or not.

Comment: You can mark any of the given answer as [accepted.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible chances

- The first thing is that u might have not sending the data to the servlet for thumbnail filed
- if the request.getParameter() method returns the null value the single & will never work , because 
  the returned value is null and you are trying to perform the action .equals so the obvious thing is it throws an  nullpointer Exception where if the string is null it doesn't allow you to perform all the actions

Comment: 1 What means "not sending the data to the servlet for thumbnail filed"? It is an input field and declared between form field, so must be sent after submitting.
2 I tried to do the same with the text type of input tag and got the same result.

Comment: its a typo (field).... once remove the following line                  <input type="file" name="file" multiple id="file"   onchange="check('file')"/><br> and  encrypt , because your are declared encrypt is multipart so i think it never works with request.getParameter() , you need to check with request.getPart() or other related methods, it will work sure