# How to count multiple checked checkbox in each row of a table in jsp

Tags: jsp, checkbox

I have multiple check-boxes in each row of a table in a "jsp" page and I want to count number of checked check-boxes in each row of the table and display it's  counter corresponding to each row on the same page.

I don't have any ideas on how to do it.

Comment: This will help to get it started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775412/checking-which-check-boxes-are-selected-using-java-a-jsp

Comment: Are you using JavaScript/jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, attach a change event to the check-boxes and count the number of checked items in each row.  Once you get the count, you can display it where ever you like.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $('#checkBoxTable tr').each(function() {
        var count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
        $(this).find('.cbCount').html(count + ' checkboxes checked.');
    });
});
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xo67Ljtk/) for you to see how it works.